# Eclipse: An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project". org/apache/maven/plugin/war/util/MappingUtils

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-wtp

Adding a dependency on pom.xml and updating via  `Maven  ->  Update Project`  I get this error (see .log below)

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2012-08-22 10:04:31.078 !MESSAGE An
>   internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project". !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/maven/plugin/war/util/MappingUtils     at
>   org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.namemapping.PatternBasedFileNameMapping.mapFileName(PatternBasedFileNameMapping.java:36)
>     at
>   org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.WebProjectConfiguratorDelegate.configureClasspath(WebProjectConfiguratorDelegate.java:367)
>     at
>   org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.WTPProjectConfigurator.configureClasspath(WTPProjectConfigurator.java:95)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DefaultClasspathManagerDelegate.populateClasspath(DefaultClasspathManagerDelegate.java:61)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.getClasspath(BuildPathManager.java:303)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.getClasspath(BuildPathManager.java:411)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.getClasspath(BuildPathManager.java:392)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.getClasspath(BuildPathManager.java:419)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.updateClasspath(BuildPathManager.java:240)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.mavenProjectChanged(BuildPathManager.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.notifyProjectChangeListeners(ProjectRegistryManager.java:724)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.applyMutableProjectRegistry(ProjectRegistryManager.java:847)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:280)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:323)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:74)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse, m2e and the m2e extensions?

Comment: Eclipse Juno Build id: 20120614-1722 - m2e 1.1.0.10120530

Comment: Did you ever get this problem fixed?  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the `maven-war-plugin` in your POM and make sure it's `2.2`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a late answer, but I ran into the same problem and I fixed it by deleting my Maven repository.  /.m2/repository